# 'p4 where' find right location of a targe file, but p4 edit says 'file(s) not on client'

Tags: perforce

`p4 where target` works well.

It tells me right location of a target file.

But `p4 edit target' says 'target - file(s) not on client.`

How can I fix this problem?

=================================================================

```
E:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src>p4 where manager.h
//depot/project/src/manager.h //jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180/project/src/manager.h e:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src\manager.h

e:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src>p4 edit manager.h
manager.h - file(s) not on client.
```

====================================================================

update : 12/5/2016

```
E:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src>p4 where manager.h
//depot/project/src/manager.h //jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180/project/src/manager.h e:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src\manager.h

e:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src>p4 sync manager.h
manager.h - no such file(s).
```

====================================================================

update : 12/6/2016

```
E:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src>p4 where manager.h
//depot/project/src/manager.h //jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180/project/src/manager.h e:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src\manager.h


E:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src>dir e:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src\manager.h

 Volume in drive E is SSD
 Volume Serial Number is CCFE-A2E3

 Directory of E:\p4\jungho-ahn_DESKTOP_6180\project\src

2016-12-05  PM 02:02            36,052 manager.h
               1 File(s)         36,052 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  403,746,885,632 bytes free
```

There is the file and I can Check Out on p4v.

Comment: could you provide the section of code which is applicable to this question, it can be hard for answerers to find an answer for you if they can't see the context

Comment: Sounds like you don't currently have that file sync'd. What does `p4 sync -n manager.h` say? How about `p4 filelog manager.h`?

Comment: `p4 where` doesn't tell if the file exists or not.  It tells you what the locations *would be* if the file does exist.  Are you sure that this file actually exists?  Are you sure that you've spelled and capitalized it correctly? (It shouldn't matter, but you've misspelled "project" in the directory structure of your client.)

Answer (score 3):

The error "file(s) not on client" suggests that the file has not been synced to your client.  Try:

```
p4 sync manager.h
p4 edit manager.h
```

Note that the file might fail to sync for reasons that have nothing to do with your client view -- if the sync command fails it should give you an error message that tells you why this file can't be synced to your client.

For example, if `p4 sync` says `no such file(s)` it means that the file is either nonexistent or deleted.  (You can run `p4 files manager.h` to see if the file exists and what its head action is.)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the File location is mapped in your connection settings.

Use the full depot path. //depot/project/src/manager.h

p4 edit //depot/project/src/manager.h

or p4 edit "//depot/project/src/manager.h"

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this issue. `p4 set` displayed everything right. Even `p4 where` was fine.

However `p4 where <target-file>` gave out the complete mapping for the target file. Which helped in understanding that `//depot/my-repo...` was missing a slash in my view.

So I changed it to /`/depot/my-repo/...` and did a `p4 sync`. All files got refreshed.

Now `p4 edit` works without any issue.